# Laravel update database if date matches today

Tags: php, laravel

The user is able to enter the amount of rain collected each day, by entering the amount of rain collected, and date. They should be able to enter rain collected in the past as well (by giving another date if needed).

So, how can i check (by using the created_at row) if the user has already entered some data for the current date? And if they have, update the value given for the specific date. I already know how to update etc, I just need a way to validate the date given.

I was trying to figure something out by using Carbon, But my head is about to explode, I can't seem to wrap my mind around this issue.

```
'created_at','>=',Carbon::today())
```

I know that wont work. The created_at looks like this:

```
2014-07-16 20:42:38
```

So I would need a way to check the current date, and skip the time/clock? How would my approach be on this?

Comment: Why don't you just use Carbon::now() it gives you nice Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: Did you try `whereDate` as I mentioned in answer?

Comment: @C2486 Yes, marked your answer as correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your condition in query like below, to match only date in `yyyy-mm-dd`, to check the current date.

```
 ->whereDate('created_at','=',Carbon::today()->format("Y-m-d") )
```

Comment: Am I wrong or isn't that invalid? I mean, the created_at also has the time included, or would that be ignored?

Comment: @Catherine91 :  With `whereDate` time will be ignored

Comment: I didn't know that whereDate did ignore the time, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

[See how you can work with dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)